# Visual Studio Build Release with DotNetZip

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dotnetzip

I've written a program in C# that uses DotNetZip but when I go to build the exe in Release configuration it can't find Ionic.

I followed these instructions:
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting-Started&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Do you get a compiler error or do you get an error when you run your executable outside visual studio?

Comment: could you post the compile error?

Comment: Warning 1 The referenced component 'Ionic.Zip' could not be found.

Comment: And in debug mode it compiles without errors?

Comment: Yes. And when in Debug for Build Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added a reference to Ionic.Zip.dll in your references.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using ILMerge with ILMergeGui to merge the Ionic.Zip.dll with my .exe